# How do I change the Date Format of a .net SOAP request?

Tags: .net, soap

I'm using a WSDL that expects a DateTime parameter for one of the methods.  When .NET serializes my call, it creates a date parameter like this:

2010-1-1T10:00:00.00

This looks like the serializer is using a date format of "s". I need a different format, namely one with the timezone offset:

2010-1-1T10:00:00.00 -4:00

How do I specify the date format I want the serializer to use? (C# or VB.NET)

Comment: That's not how SoapFormatter serializes DateTime, it looks like this: "2010-05-05T16:57:27.5270036-05:00".  Note the seconds fraction and the 2 digit month and day.  No idea how you'd get yours.

Comment: You're right. I typed in the example incorrectly. The leading zeros are needed, and the space before -04:00 should be removed.

Comment: Thanks Hans, this worked for me perfectly, BUT what does these last digits stand for ".5270036-05:00"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the timezone offset is for your current timezone, you should check that your DateTime instance has its `Kind` property set to `DateTimeKind.Local`.  If not, you can force it as follows:

```
DateTime myDateTime;
...
myDateTime = myDateTime.SpecifyKind(myDateTime, DateTimeKind.Local);
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually this would be done by passing Time / Date in the UTC (Universal Time Coordinated) format... meaning: Worldtime and putting the timezone (if needed) in a seperate parameter.

See:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.touniversaltime%28VS.71%29.aspx

Comment: That's a fine idea, but my question is HOW do I get the serializer for SOAP calls to use some format instead of its default format?

(In any event, the service I'm calling doesn't accept that format - I tried it using SoapUI)