# String to Datetime conversion

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

When I enter the value `25.12.2011`, this error appears:

```
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. 
   ---> System.InvalidCastException: Conversion from string to type 'Date' is not valid.
```

Comment: Why do you want to solve this `Conversion` error directly from your `web.config`? Maybe you should update your question, is `25.12.2011` a user-entered value?

Comment: I can solve the problem with datetime.tryparseExact but there are lots of lines so there will be lots of errors. 
User enter his/her birrthdate forexample: 20.01.2000 this causes error but if his/her enter it such as 01.20.2000 there is no error.

Comment: Are you using `DateTimeControls`? This is more of `data-validation`, I think `web.config` has nothing to do with it. You might as well create a validation function, in server or client, to validate the date entered by the user.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably expecting the date in a different format, such as `yyyy-mm-dd` or (assuming american formatting) `mm/dd/yyyy`.

Comment: I understand but can I solve this problem without changing any code ? for example is there a solution only changing web.config or another?

Comment: Closest i found is this, but it still needs a code change. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774862/how-do-i-change-the-date-format-of-a-net-soap-request

Comment: I guess if i change some codes all of them give lots of errors so i struggle to solve this problem without changing any code :) 
but thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

you can do [TryParseExact()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044.aspx)

```
 if (DateTime.TryParseExact("25.12.2011", "dd.mm.yyyy", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                                DateTimeStyles.None, out dateValue))
{
   string s = Convert.ToString(dateValue);
}
```

If you want to format to particular format see [String.Format](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/)

Comment: I understand but can I solve this problem without changing any code ?
for example is there a solution only changing web.config or another?

Comment: thank you I see. are there any method in order to solve this problem from web config?

Comment: what you are looking in web.config? cultureinfo or dateformat?

Comment: you can set your culture information read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508.aspx